# CORS issue in express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am getting cors error with this code.
I have applied the cross origin headers too. Please tell me the solution for this.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });


router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('Yippeee! You found me.');
});
router.post('/postTest',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.use('/',router);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Where is your app hosted?

Comment: Are you sending credentials in your request? Which port is your frontend served from?

Comment: App is using ExtJS. Port used is 1841

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a specific answer because there's so many unknowns in your question. However you could give the [CORS plugin](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) a shot:

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```